# Creating a VF page ‘Registration Form’ for Account object is Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com, sfdc

I have below requirement to Create a VF page – ‘**Registration Form**’ having

1.**Name** field

2.**Attachment area** – where we can browse and add any document there

Expected UI-[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59BUz.png)

Below is my VF code-

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="InputFileControllerExtension"> 
    <apex:messages /> 
    <apex:form id="theForm"> 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Personal Details" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload and save" action="{!save}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
            </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Below is the APEX Class-

```
    public class InputFileControllerExtension
{
    private final Account acct;
    public Attachment attachment {get;set;}
    public PageReference save()
    {
        attachment.parentid = acct.id;
        insert attachment;
        return stdController.save();
    }
    public InputFileControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    { 
        attachment = new Attachment();
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        this.stdController = stdController;
    } 
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
}
```

Error I am getting-

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]
>   Error is in expression '{!save}' in component  in page file_upload_test: Class.InputFileControllerExtension.save: line 8, column 1

could you please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saving the Account record at the end of your save() method?  Why not just view it using

```
stdController.view()
```